# How to download large files from a server from frontend (VueJS) using fetch or axios. Achieve simultaneous download while fetching

Tags: node.js, express, axios, download, fetch

My frontend (written in VueJS) needs to download a large file from a server (~1GB but can get even larger). My current approach is using [streamSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamsaver) however, although this seems to work fine when I download files while testing locally, it seems to struggle when testing it on other devices (android phone while pointing the server to 0.0.0.0)

Front end Code for downloading, I'm currently piping the fetch data to streamSaver, however from what I understand, the fetch request has to complete before the download action starts, which isn't really the solution I require. I want to be able to start the download simultaneously.

```js
const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(fileName);
const res = await fetch("gets/download-file?" + new URLSearchParams({
    relPath: path.join(forPath, fileName)
}))
const readableStream = res.body
if (window.WritableStream && readableStream.pipeTo) {
    return readableStream.pipeTo(fileStream)
        .then(() => console.log('done writing'))
}
window.writer = fileStream.getWriter()

const reader = res.body.getReader()
const pump = () => reader.read()
    .then(res => res.done
        ? window.writer.close()
        : window.writer.write(res.value).then(pump))

pump()
```

My server is written in express.js, and I have also tried streaming the data from the server side as well

```js
router.get("/download-file", checkPath, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const relativePath = req.query.relPath;
        const fullPath = path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, relativePath);
        console.log(green("Downloading: ", fullPath))
        // res.sendFile(fullPath, (err) => {
        //     if (err) console.log(red(err))
        // })
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        fs.createReadStream(fullPath).pipe(res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(red(err))
    }
})
```

I have seen [Stream large blob file using StreamSaver.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67776919/stream-large-blob-file-using-streamsaver-js), and other similar answers but they all seem to have similar flaws of having to complete the fetch request and wait till then before streaming a download, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: I had figured out how to do this. Basically instead of using the fetch api and trying to use javascript to download a file, you should let the browser handle the download. You just need to serve the file from your backend - `res.download` or sendFile in node and then navigate to the file directly (like how an anchor tag would do it)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you did this?  I'm trying to do the same thing.  When a user clicks a link to download a large file, the browser should immediately prompt them for where to save it, and then handle simultaneous downloads in the background.  I do not want the user to wait for the API backend to return the entire file.

Comment: @Bruno71 I have added an answer below as requested. Again, essentially you want to handle the download like an anchor tag would. Navigate to the url where the file is served and let the browser handle the download. Hope the answer helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this so I'm answering my question.
Basically instead of using the fetch api and trying to use javascript to download a file, you should let the browser handle the download. You just need to serve the file from your backend - res.download or sendFile in node and then navigate to the file directly (like how an anchor tag would do it)

Adding an example as requested.

so on your client let's say you have a download button that downloads some file path, so you would have code that looks like this

### Client

```js
function downloadFile(event: MouseEvent) {
    const fileName = figure.querySelector("figcaption")?.dataset.filename;
    const fullpath = window.location.pathname + fileName;
    if (fileName) {
        window.location.href = `/download?pathname=${fullpath}`;
    }
}
```

and for this your server would have to serve the requested file at that particular location i.e. `/download?pathname=${fullpath}`

### Server - express

**main.ts**

```js
import { router as downloadRouter } from "@routes/download";
app.use("/download", downloadRouter);
```

**this is a route - download.ts**

```js
router.get("/", async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const pathname = req.query.pathname as string;
    const baseFolder = (await settings).uploadfolder;
    const fullPath = path.join(baseFolder, pathname);
    console.log("fullPath: ", fullPath);
    res.sendFile(fullPath);
});
```

Comment: OK, thanks!  In my scenario, I have a Vue frontend and a C# API backend, both hosted at the same URL.  What I was missing was to allow the backend API to serve the static files.  Then the frontend could use a link to download the files directly (ie. https://url.com/rootfolder/subfolder/filename.ext)

Comment: They are MP3 files in a root folder called "audio".  I had to add this to my Program.cs file for the API...

`app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "audio")),
    RequestPath = "/audio",
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        // Force download for all files in the "audio" folder
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
    }
});`

Comment: @Bruno71 Ah yeah, a good way to check this is to manually visit the url and see if the file is accessible at that endpoint, you should either be able to see it directly in the browser or it may start the download, at least on express if you want to start the download automatically you'd use `res.download(fullPath);` and compared to `res.sendFile(fullPath);`.  Glad you found your solution though!